# How to wrap SOL with Solana cli?

Tags: solana

I am struggling to find a command to wrap SOL via CLI, please help. I could not find this command in official documentation. Also I could not find this subcommand with `solana --help`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found what I was doing wrong, it is spl-token cli, not Solana cli

```
spl-token wrap 1
```